# Unable to find Apex action method referenced as 'metadataInsertUpdate.handleInsertAndUpdate'

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, deployment-error

I am trying to deploy a lightning web component where I have referenced the apex class named 'metadataInsertUpdate'. The apex class is already there in the target org. But still getting this error as apex class not found.
I have gone through some suggestions found in other threads :

1. Confirmed that the class is there in target org.
2. Compiled all classes in the org.

Please let me know if it is an issue with the code. I am trying to get profile name and permission set names in two input fields and pass it to the apex class so that a custom metadata record can be created with the info.

**metadataInsertUpdate :**

```
public class metadataInsertUpdate implements Metadata.DeployCallback {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {

            System.debug('success: '+ result);
            } else {      
            System.debug(' fail: '+ result);
            }
    }

    public static void handleInsertAndUpdate (String fullName, String label, Map<String, Object> fieldWithValuesMap){

        Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        customMetadata.fullName = fullName;
        customMetadata.label = label;
        
        for (String key: fieldWithValuesMap.keySet()) {
        
           Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
           customField.field = key;
           customField.value = fieldWithValuesMap.get(key);
           customMetadata.values.add(customField);
        }
        
        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer(); 
        mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
        metadataInsertUpdate callback = new metadataInsertUpdate();       
        Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
        
        }
        
}
```

**permissionSetAssign.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import handleInsertAndUpdate from '@salesforce/apex/metadataInsertUpdate.handleInsertAndUpdate';

export default class PermissionSetAssign extends LightningElement {

    handleSubmit(event) {

        //handle onclick event
        let profile = this.template.querySelector(`[name="profile"]`);
        let permissions = this.template.querySelector(`[name="permissions"]`);
        //// Map<String, Object> or a single mapping
        var object = {'Profile__c': profile, 'Permissions__c': permissions};
        //The developerName is Profile_Permission.ProfileName and label is ProfileName
        handleInsertAndUpdate('Profile_Permission.'+profile , profile , object);

    }
}
```

**permissionSetAssign.html :**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="Add Profile and Permission Sets">

        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter the profile" name = "profile" placeholder="type here..." maxlength="25"></lightning-input>

        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter the permissiosets semicolon seperated"  name = "permissions" placeholder="type here..." maxlength="25"></lightning-input>

        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>  

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: try adding the `@AuraEnabled` annotation to your apex method, and then deploy your LWC component.

Comment: Hi, It worked after adding @AuraEnabled. Thanks